# How to change all file and folder permissions in the same folder using node.js

Tags: node.js, permissions, fs

I want remove all read only attributes after my project is built.

I tried `fs.chmodSync('path',0o741)`

It works when the path is a file, but doesn’t work when the path is a folder.
Is there something like `chmod -R` in linux that changes all the permissions in the folder in node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the [chmodr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chmodr) module.

```
var chmodr = require('chmodr');

chmodr('/folder', 0o777, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Failed to execute chmod', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Success');
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can look at its [implementation](https://github.com/isaacs/chmodr/blob/master/chmodr.js), it's a small 100 line file, it calls `fs.chmod`/`fs.chmodSync` recursively on all children of a directory.

Comment: Thanks!, I don't want to add more modules(it's too much) in my project but i can try its implementation, it is useful.

Comment: @mihai I'm sure `chmodr` is fine, but the `fs` module actually provides the tools for this - just pick your favorite search algorithm and implement it in Node.js. See below for an implementation using BFS. I broke it into functions for clarity, but it's really fewer than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Node.js script that uses the built-in module `fs` to recursively `chmod` a directory.

[Source code is here too](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angstyloop/nodejs-utils/main/chmodRecursive.js).

But please note [these concerns](https://github.com/nodejs/tooling/issues/59) about the vulnerability to [TOCTOU attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

`USAGE: ./chmodRecursive <DIRECTORY> <PERMISSIONS>`

`PERMISSIONS is a three character string, like 777.`

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const { readdirSync, lstatSync, isDirectory, chmodSync } = require('fs');
const { join, posix: { basename } } = require('path');

/** List subdirectories of target directory @d. NOT recursive.
 * @param dir - (string) Target directory.
 * @return (string[]) Subdirectories of @d.
 */
function listDirs(dir) {
    return readdirSync(dir)
            .map(it => join(dir, it))
            .filter(it => lstatSync(it).isDirectory());
}

/** List files (and subdirectories) in target directory @dir. NOT recursive.
 * @param dir - (string) Full or relative path of target directory.
 * @return (string[]) Files of @dir.
 */
function listChildren(dir) {
    return readdirSync(dir).map(it => join(dir, it));
}

/** chmod all files (and subdirectories) in a directory @dir, giving them new
 * permissions @perms. NOT recursive.
 *
 * @param dir - (string) Full or relative path of target directory.
 * @perms - (string) Permissions for chmod, as a string (e.g., '644')
 */
function chmodChildren(dir, perms) {
    listChildren(dir).map(it => chmodSync(it, perms));
}

/* Starting in the directory named @root, recursively find and chmod all
 * all files and subdirectories. The directory @root is also chmod'd.
 * Implements BFS with a FIFO queue.
 *
 * @root - Full or relative path of directory to start in.
 * @perms - (string) Permissions for chmod, as a string (e.g., '644')
 *
 */
/*module.exports = */function chmodRecursive(root, perms) {
    let dir = root;
    chmodSync(root, perms);
    chmodChildren(root, perms);
    const dirs = listDirs(dir);
    while (dirs.length) {
        dir = dirs.shift();
        chmodChildren(dir, perms);
        dirs.push(...listDirs(dir));
    }
}

const EXIT_SUCCESS = 0;
const EXIT_FAILURE = 1;

/** Driver code.
 */
function main() {
    // "node" and the name of the script are always the first two arguments.
    // Your command line arguments start at index=2 (the third argument -
    // totally not confusing, right?)
    if (process.argv.length !== 4) {
        console.log('USAGE: ./chmodRecursive <DIRECTORY> <PERMISSIONS>');
        console.log('PERMISSIONS is a three character string, like 777.');
        process.exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    chmodRecursive(...process.argv.slice(2));
    process.exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

main();
```